# Spring boot test : How to test a controller with jpa data

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-test

I want to test a controller with jpa data.

How can i do it?

I have this controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class AuthenticateController {
    @Autowired private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired private ClientRepository client;
    @Autowired private JwtUtil jwt;
    @Autowired private UserDetailsService details;
    @PostMapping("/authenticate") public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticate) throws Exception {
        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticate.getIdentification(), authenticate.getPassword()));
        }
        catch (BadCredentialsException e) { throw new Exception("Incorrect username or password", e); }
        final UserDetails userDetails = details.loadUser(authenticate.getIdentification());
        final String jwt = this.jwt.generateToken(userDetails);
        final String identification = userDetails.getIdentification();
        Client c = client.findByUsernameOrEmailOrPhone(identification, identification, identification).orElseThrow();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new AuthenticationResponse(jwt, c));
    }
}
```

and this jpa data

```
public interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<Client, Integer> {
}
```

Comment: I understand you're asking for an integration test? You could create fake users before running your test, see [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-data-sql-and-schema-sql) for examples

Comment: i don't want a fake users, i just want to use jpa repository with a rest controller in test. so i don't know what annotations i should use because i cant use `@WebMvcTest` and `@JpaDataTest` in the same time

Comment: Please clarify what the exact problem is you are facing. What have you tried, and in what way was the result different from your expectations. As it currently stands a full answer to the question would fill a small book.

Comment: 'i cant use @WebMvcTest and @JpaDataTest in the same time' - Well, use `@SpringBootTest`, then